# RMA'ed device configuration

Tags: cisco, switch, router, juniper, aruba

Just wondering what are the methods that you use when re-configuring an RMA'ed device.
Do you manually configured all the script that runs on the device or is there any efficient ways configuring the device without manually configuring it.

Comment: All depends on the  kind of device, no?

Comment: ... and your device management (where you might just need to reassign the config).

Answer (score 2):

After you power up the new device and update any soft/firmware, you can simply upload a backup of the device configuration.  You *do* have a backup of the configuration, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you either mean 'What do you do before you RMA a device' or 'What do you do when you purchase a refurbished/used device':

For the first one, if it is in working condition enough to do so, simply set it to factory default or delete the configuration before returning it.

For the second, basically the same. Factory reset and then update any firmware or software before beginning initial setup and testing.

Comment: ... and don't forget the required certificates including private keys. Commonly, those aren't exported with a config backup but need to be either reimported or regenerated.